# Issuse passing output from rs_get_frame_data() to GStreamer

Tags: casting, gstreamer, realsense

I am trying to pass the output from `librealsense` library function, `rs_get_frame_data` on to `Gstreamer`. Before I do that, I need to copy the output to a local memory char buffer and then send that buffer over to `GStreamer`.  I am having some issue with typecasting the output. The data from `GSTREAMER` does not look right.

```
char *buffer = malloc (...)
....
struct rgb *rgb = rs_get_frame_data  (...);
....
memcpy (buffer,rgb,sizeof(rgb)):
Pass buffer to Gstreamer.
```

Is anything wrong with the above?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have done is only copy one pointer size (4bytes) OR one RGB struct size, since your declaration is ambiguous. If you want to copy the whole frame, you should multiply how many pixels inside the frame for the copy.